# Two VPN connections on Windows 7

Tags: windows, networking, vpn

I have three laptops running Windows 7. I'd like to set one up as a server and have the other two connect through VPN, so they can access the server anywhere. The problem is Windows 7 only accepts one connection at a time. Is there any free software I can install too get round this? Would I only need to install it on the server?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for can be solved in two ways.  One, get the server version of Windows and the VPN issue goes away.  If that's not feasible, then you're left with open source alternatives and they aren't as easy to configure as the Windows variant.  That being said, OpenVPN works very, very well once it's up and running.  [Take a look over here](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html) for more information on how to install it.

Good luck!

Comment: Three ways really - OP can use "hardware-VPN termination before server" solution